# How to convert list into dict using python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Input:

```py
list = [['What did the Vedas contain large collections of?'],
        ['What did the Vedas contain large collections of?'],
        ['What was accompanied by the rise of ascetic movements in Greater Magadha?'],
        ['In what part of India did Wootz steel originate?'],
        ['What country was ruled by dynasties during the Classical period?']]
```

Output:

```py
dict = [{'question': 'What did the Vedas contain large collections of?'},
        {'question': 'What did the Vedas contain large collections of?'},
        {'question': 'What was accompanied by the rise of ascetic movements in Greater Magadha?'}]
```

I have a 2D list. How do I convert it into a dict as shown in the example?

Comment: They in the dict should be the same?

Comment: don't use `list` and `dict` as names. Check [ask]. Show what have you tried so far.

Comment: How about this : `list(map(lambda x: {'question' : x[0]}, lst))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just traverse the list, create a dictionary for each element and append them to the new variable `d`:

```
l=[['What did the Vedas contain large collections of?'], ['What did the Vedas contain large collections of?'], ['What was accompanied by the rise of ascetic movements in Greater Magadha?'], ['In what part of India did Wootz steel originate?'], ['What country was ruled by dynasties during the Classical period?']]
d = []

for i in l:
    d.append({"question":i[0]})
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'question': 'What did the Vedas contain large collections of?'}, {'question': 'What did the Vedas contain large collections of?'}, {'question': 'What was accompanied by the rise of ascetic movements in Greater Magadha?'}, {'question': 'In what part of India did Wootz steel originate?'}, {'question': 'What country was ruled by dynasties during the Classical period?'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res = [{'question': x[0]} for x in list]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your example in output You have list again. But in any case you can use this code:

```
mydict = [{"question":e[0]} for e in mylist]
```

PS I'm renamed your vars named `list`, `dict` to `mylist`, `mydict` because it's not so good practice to use class names from standard lib for local vars.